# SQL Subquery and joins

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables available

```
EMP(empname PK, empno, sal, comm, deptno, hiredate, job, mgr)

DEPT(depnto, dname, loc)
```

The queries are

a)Display the ename and dname who is earning the first highest salary

They have given a statement this has to be done using only subqueries and Join

So i started like this:

```
select A.ename, B.dname from emp A, dept B where A.deptno=B.deptno
```

and i tried various perm&comb, but i couldn't get the join statement...

This is not a homework problem, i am just trying to solve the exercise problem given in my textbook..Thanks in advance

Comment: `textbook exercises` should be an alias to `homework` :)

Comment: OK, so what if the question was to find the max salary - can you write the SQL for that? Can you then use that to query by salary i.e. can you write a query to find the name and department for a given salary? (Incidentally what you've written is an old-style join.)

Comment: Are you using a very old textbook? Your existing query uses the implicit join syntax, but a textbook written in the past twenty years really ought to be using the ANSI-92 explicit join syntax (unless it was written for an RDBMS that did not support that syntax).

Comment: @MarkBannister - [Might have been written by Celko](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=162162)

Comment: @MartinSmith: I guess my SQL coding abilities have been getting weaker as I get older ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To get the record with the max salary I've [Ordered by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) `e.sal DESC`. This will order the records in terms of salary, with the highest at the top (`DESC` = Descending, and therefore highest-lowest).

Then I've used [`TOP 1`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) to only return 1 record.

To get the `dname` I've **[joined](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)** the tables relating the 2 `deptno` columns.

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.empname
            ,d.dname
FROM [EMP] e
JOIN [DEPT] d ON d.deptno=e.deptno
ORDER BY e.sal DESC
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT emp.ename,dept.dname FROM emp
        JOIN dept ON emp.deptno=dept.deptno
        WHERE emp.sal=(SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp)
```